# Code Written for .NET 4 returning Error For .NET 3.5 Client

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, irc

I am trying to take a library Coded for .NET 4 and recompile it to use .NET 3.5 Client. The library is available at https://github.com/cshivers/IrcClient-csharp/tree/master/IrcClient-csharp

This is the block of Code in my program that gets an error when Calling Irc.ChannelMessage in the external library.

```
  Private Sub irc_ChannelMessage(Channel As String, User As String, Message As String) Handles irc.ChannelMessage
        rtbOutput.Clear()
        rtbOutput.Text = Message
        If rtbOutput.Text.StartsWith("!Listen ") Then
            Dim s As String = rtbOutput.Text
            Dim pars As New List(Of String)(s.Split(" "c))

            CheckParams(pars)
        End If
    End Sub
```

The Library works for my program when it is set to use .NET 4, however when I set it to use .Net 3.5 Client it returns the error below

> Error 4   Method 'Private Sub irc_ChannelMessage(Channel As String, User
>   As String, Message As String)' cannot handle event 'Public Event
>   ChannelMessage(sender As Object, e As
>   TechLifeForum.ChannelMessageEventArgs)' because they do not have a
>   compatible signature.

It seems That once I compile it for .NET 3.5 The IrcClient.cs can't translate it to EventArguments.cs properly...

in IrcClient.cs We are calling

```
 public event EventHandler<ChannelMessageEventArgs> ChannelMessage = delegate { };
```

and that should then call This from EventArguments.cs:

```
public class ChannelMessageEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Channel { get; internal set; }
        public string From { get; internal set; }
        public string Message { get; internal set; }
        public ChannelMessageEventArgs(string Channel, string From, string Message)
        {
            this.Channel = Channel;
            this.From = From;
            this.Message = Message;
        }
    }
```

However it will only work in .NET 4 any IDEAS?

Comment: Why don't you modify irc_ChannelMessage to have compatible signature.

Comment: @USR, Because I need the IRC info That the EventArgs will put out, not the call to Event Args that this refrences

Comment: As I Said the code worked fine with .Net 4, but when switched to .NET 3.5 This error started

Comment: The "IRC info" is right there in the method arguments (`Channel As String, User As String, Message As String`). Why can't you use that?

Comment: @USR, I am trying to use that. It is suppose to be referenced by the event arg:  public event EventHandler<ChannelMessageEventArgs> ChannelMessage = delegate { };                                however it wont go to the Event Arguments

Comment: the code worked fine with .Net 4

Comment: You probably have a different version of the library now. Changing the .NET version does not change event signatures. Simply adapt your method signature to the new event signature! The event changed so change your handler as well.

Comment: @USR, I don't normally write in C#. Could you provide an example of What you said in the previous comment based on the code in the github link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up an event handler (`Handles` keyword), the signature of the method (in other words, the variables passed to the method) must match the signature of the event.

Your event's signature is (C#):

```
EventHandler<ChannelMessageEventArgs> ChannelMessage
```

(vb.net):

```
EventHandler(EventArgs as ChannelMessageEventArgs)
```

You are incorrectly trying to handle this event with the following signature:

```
irc_ChannelMessage(Channel As String, User As String, Message As String)
```

These three variables are contained within the ChannelMessageEventArgs class, and passed together, therefore you can change your event handling method to:

```
Private Sub irc_ChannelMessage(EventArgs As ChannelMessageEventArgs) Handles irc.ChannelMessage
    rtbOutput.Clear()
    rtbOutput.Text = EventArgs.Message
    If rtbOutput.Text.StartsWith("!Listen ") Then
        Dim s As String = rtbOutput.Text
        Dim pars As New List(Of String)(s.Split(" "c))

        CheckParams(pars)
    End If
End Sub
```